# crystal report formula to count and average per week

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I'm trying to find a way that I can count records and then get an average of how many records were entered into the database in a 13 week period from the start date Parameter.

I tried by creating a sub-report to to detail the records that have been entered for each client. Then do a summary to count the records but here is were I'm stuck of not knowing how to get an average for a 13 week period starting from the start date parameter.

example should be = 4 records average per week entered for a 13 week period.

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a group on the date field; choose "for each week" as the grouping option.
Select a field (a key field works well); choose Insert | Summary...; choose Count for the aggregation method
Move summary field to the group-header section
Create a formula field name 'Increment'; add it to group-header section; suppress it; add this text:

```
// {@Increment}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar n:=n+Count ({TABLE.DATE}, {TABLE.DATE}, "weekly");
Numbervar d:=d+1;
```

Create a formula field name 'Average'; add it to report-footer section; add this text:

```
// {@Average}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar n;
Numbervar d;

If d<>0 then n/d
```

corrected formula as there was a typo